# How can i print empty spaces from a string?

Tags: c, string

```
     #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
           char phrase [100]={0};
           printf("Write a sentence: \n");
           scanf ("%s", phrase);
           printf("%s\n", phrase);
      }
```

The purpose of this program is to print a sentence from the user. The problem is that there is something wrong with the ' ' character and i dont know how to solve it.

During the execution, the sentence is only printed  until the first empty space, for some reason. but why?

Comment: this is how `scanf` works, use `fgets` to get whoe line

Comment: Read [part of %s of scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: `scanf` is unsafe unless you specify the destination buffer length - think about what happens if a user types in 101 or more characters.

Comment: you can make a while loop and until your character is '\0' you add characters to the string, and then print the string

Comment: @VaduvaMihaitaBogdan: "*until your character is '\0'*" which character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, the `%s` conversion specifier in `scanf` can't read strings with white spaces; it uses white spaces as delimiters. You can use [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char aLine[100];
  fgets(aLine, 100, stdin);
  aLine[strlen(aLine)-1] = '\0'; // trimming the last \n
  printf("%s\n", aLine);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_scanf can't read strings with white spaces, it uses white spaces as delimiters_" - Nope. You can. `scanf("%[^\n]", string); scanf("%*c");`. And `%s` uses whitespace as a delimiter, not `scanf` as a whole

Comment: Note that if your code encounters EOF, you have an uninitialized buffer and you've no idea how long the string is.  If the buffer is empty — the first character is the null byte — then you write to a character before the start of the array, which is undefined behaviour.